# Using JQuerys Dialog multiple times in a rails loop

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-dialog, dynamic-links

I have the following rails code in a loop that has a link for a jquery dialog.

('report_image' in this link is a helper method that simply calls an image.)

```
<%= link_to report_image, "#", :class => "flight_report_opener" %>
  <div id="flight_report_dialog" title=" FLIGHTS REPORT">
    <p>Dialog content</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The problem, of course, is that this generates multiple instance of id="flight_report_dialog" on the same page...which breaks the .dialog calls.  Can't use classes either.  I tried to change the id to be dynamically generated by adding the id generated by the loop (@ratings.each do |rating|) to the end of the dialog div css id.  Then pass that through a named function call in a link_to_function.

```
<div id="flight_report_dialog_<%= rating %>" title=" FLIGHTS REPORT"> %> </div>
```

That didnt work out for me either.

I feel like Im having a brain fart here.  Hoping someone might be able to help me get this solved.

How do I call the jquery dialog function multiple times on the same page from dynamically generated links.

The function I am currently using is this...which of course doesn't work.  Actually, just to be clear, the function works fine...on the first instance of the id called:

```
$("#flight_report_opener").click(
     function() { $( "#flight_report_dialog" ).dialog( "open" ); 
     return false; 
});
```

Comment: all previous comments were mysteriously erased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve this.  You can piece this code in to the code above...

IN THE VIEW:

```
<%= link_to report_image, "#", :class => "ground_report_opener", :data => {rating: rating.id} %>
<div class="ground_report_dialog" id="ground_report_dialog_<%= rating.id %>" title=" GROUND REPORT">
```

IN THE JS:

```
$(".flight_report_opener").click(function() { 
$( "#flight_report_dialog_"+$('.flight_report_opener').data('rating') ).dialog( "open" ); 
return false; 
});
```

Comment: I went this route after watching railscasts episode #324.  I strongly suggest you sign up for the pro version...